# geom_bar produces x-axis tick text aliased/distorted

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following minimal example reproduces the issue to a minor degree ... I noticed that the distortion depends on how much data is stacked up whereas if there is no stacked up data then there is no aliasing/distortion. The y-axis tick text is never affected only the x-axis tick text. The color/boldness difference between the x-axis tick text is also very noticeable.

```
library(ggplot2) 

x <- c(1111, 2222, 3333, 1111, 1111, 3333, 3333, 1111, 3333, 1111, 2222, 1111, 3333, 1111, 1111)
y <- c(11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 13)
z <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a')
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x, y, fill=z)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$x)
g
```

I then get the 3333 axis somewhat aliased/distorted and noticeably darker than the 1111 and 2222:

[image: aliased/distorted 3333]

Is there a way to post-process the plot and fix this?

I have tried without success:

```
library(extrafont)
ggsave(filename='myplot.pdf', plot=g)
embed_fonts('myplot.pdf')
```

**UPDATE**: If I remove `breaks=df$x` from `scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$x)` then the distortion is gone ... but I need the breaks otherwise it will not always show every x-axis tick and I need it.

Any ideas how to go around this issue and keep all the breaks without distortion?

Comment: the distortion is in in the PDF too ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your breaks are being overplotted on top of each other for every time they occur in your data. This creates the "distortion" you see. Easily remedied by using `unique(df$x)` instead of `df$x` as the breaks.